# jQuery Timepicker works locally but not on Heroku

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, timepicker

My jQuery timepicker is not rendering on Heroku. I originally had difficulty getting the jQuery to work so it could be that the way I uploaded the code is what's causing the error but the timepicker works fine locally.
I've tried running

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

but no change.

Here's my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-timepicker-jt
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap
```

And production.rb:

```
Website::Application.configure do

config.cache_classes = true
config.eager_load = true
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.version = '1.0'
config.assets.precompile += ['jquery.js', 'jquery_ujs.js']
config.log_level = :info
config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'http://app.com/' }
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem- the jquery was loading, but required a page refresh. 
So to fix the error, I added

```
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

then changed the loading order in my in application.js so turbolinks loaded after jquery

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-timepicker-jt
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `jquery-timepicker-jt` file into the `config.assets.precompile += ['jquery.js', 'jquery_ujs.js']` on your production.rb file

Or add this line into the `application.rb` file:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( jquery-timepicker-jt.js )
```

Either of those should work